# Migrate large data set to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, transfer

I am try to rename and migrate 2TB(10's of millions) of images from a local server onto amazon s3. I wrote PHP to send them using the aws library (running on the same local machine), but I don't have the 6 months it wants to finish. Looking for some ideas on doing this faster.

I have 2 ideas but not sure they would be any better....
1. Use some mounted s3 solution (s3fs) that will parallel the upload (will it???)
2. Pull the images onto an ec2 instance and send to s3 from there. I could pull them with ssh/FTP or http. Still probably need to parallel them manually??

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your 10M+ list of images into subsets. Upload each subset to S3 in parallel.

Comment: I would need 100 parallels. Seems like there has to be something that will do this for me, or at least help somewhat.

Comment: A scripting language will help you out. Perhaps you can write a wrapper shell script to automate the splitting and submission parts.

Comment: I was hoping to find something that would do this for me, but its not so bad in the end. I implemented argv parameters so I can call the upload script on distinct sets of images easily.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to [ship Amazon a hard drive](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/) with your data.